# Gradle doesn't execute external command properly

Tags: gradle, npm

I have the following gradle task to build frontend code using npm:

```
task buildFrontend() {
    doLast {
        exec {
            workingDir "src/ui"
            commandLine "npm", "install"
            commandLine "npm", "run", "build"
        }
...
}
```

However when I run the build I get the following error:

```
...
> Task :solutions:dash:buildFrontend FAILED

...
> ng build --base-href /p/ --prod

sh: 1: ng: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! dash@0.0.0 build: `ng build --base-href /p/ --prod`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the dash@0.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
...

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':solutions:dash:buildFrontend'.
> Process 'command 'npm'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
...
```

But when I `cd` to the `src/ui` directory and run `npm install` from the terminal and then re-run the gradle build it will be successful.
It seems that Gradle doesn't execute
`commandLine "npm", "install"` in the same way and with the same result as I do it manually from the terminal.

But why? Both commands - gradle build and manual `npm install` are executed by the same user from the terminal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I've splitted the `exec` block into two as shown below:

```
exec {
    workingDir "src/ui"
    commandLine "npm", "install"
}
exec {
    workingDir "src/ui"
    commandLine "npm", "run", "build"
}
```

the app has been built without errors.